# Instagram Sandbox User invites never received

Tags: instagram-api

Our simple company app that pulls in tagged posts was Sandboxed as of June 1. I know that we don't need to go through the review process- we're going to leave it in Sandbox.

I'm trying to add Sandbox Users. I have added the username and clicked the Save button. That user never receives an email, and when I log in to the developer dashboard as the invited user, I don't see a pending invite. In fact, even when I use the Sandbox Invites button at the top of the dashboard, it's impossible to get past the Developer Signup form. I don't want to create a new app with this user, I just want to accept an invite from our company account!

I've submitted a ticket with Instagram support and have not received a reply.

Additionally, I don't understand why, when I use the Sandbox Invites button from our company account, I see a message stating:

> "You are not a Sandbox user for any client and there are no pending requests."

Obviously the account that created the app is a Sandbox user, and I have confirmed that this account can post new content that is pulled in to our feed.

Answer (score 59):

Login here https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/sandbox_invites/ and click Accept.

The invite acceptance isn't by email. It's done via the API.

Comment: Where should the user get in the developer site to accept the invite? Thanks @Viraf

Comment: They have a weird javascript issue. You need to add the invited user and hit  enter that will add the invited user to the list and then press save.

Comment: I did so, and the status of the user to be invited changed to "pending". But this user never received any invitation. I am trying now the solution of subtlegusto ...

Comment: @Jacob have you got the answer to: `Where should the user get in the developer site to accept the invite?`

Comment: @viraf how and where to send the invited user for logging in and accepting the invitation?

Answer (score 10):

Instagram has not replied to any of my help requests. For lack of other options, I went ahead and registered my personal account (the invited user) as a Developer. Magically, this allowed me to see the invitation using the Sandbox Invites button. Fill out this silly form to register as a Developer:

https://www.instagram.com/developer/register/

While this partially answers my question (it seems very strange that I never received an email as part of the invitation process), the fact that a user must register as a Developer is pointless and, worse, *undocumented*.

The documentation available here says nothing about the requirements for becoming a Sandbox User - other than simply accepting the invitation.

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

In short, I've spent time over the last week trying to untangle this mess, and I just want to be able to pull in posts that contain a hashtag.

Geez.

Comment: Hi @subtlegusto, Did you get any further in ascertaining why you can't even use the company account? I'm having the same problem - I can't comment on my own posts.

Comment: @Seano It's been a long time since I messed with this. But reading back over my old post, I think I was able to create tagged posts in the company account that were pulled into the feed.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. The procedure is the following:

- Add the sandbox user on your main account at the Developer console
- Log in to Instagram as a sandbox user (just use a different web browser is more convenient) and then go to the Doveloper console
- First accept the Developer program (the name might be different) by adding the URL and descriptons. I just filled in dummies.
- Then go to the Sandbox Invites tab and accept the invite.